# How to generate api.dfp.refreshToken?

Tags: api, oauth, google-dfp

I'm just getting started using Google's DFP API using their java libraries.  And it seems step 1 is to get a login to use the API.  Their examples/docs strongly suggest I should use OAuth2 for this purpose, however I can't get it to work.

I've gotten my api.dfp.clientId & api.dfp.clientSecret from https://code.google.com/apis/console#access and I'm running GetRefreshToken to try to get my api.dfp.refreshToken but it doesn't work.  Specifically when I use the URL given by GetRefreshToken to generate the token I get an error that says:

"Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered redirect URI"

Any ideas what is wrong?  I'm completely stuck at this point.  Perhaps I should be using something other than OAuth2?

Thanks,
-Dave

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply a redirect URI along with the oath request.  The URI that is passed must match the one you specified in the console (https://code.google.com/apis/console#access)

Answer (score 0):

I think you created a Web Application in Cloud Console. Instead - 
try create a native application. This will change the behavior of the REDIRECT URI-fields, and set them to urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and localhost.